# How to get rowIndex in extjs widget column

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I need a button in a widget column to know its rowIndex in an ExtJS 6 panel.grid, so that on button click it can use that functionality.  I know I can pull that information from the renderer function, but that seems to execute before the button has been created.  Any ideas on how I can get the index?

Comment: Seems like you're asking the wrong question here. Could you not use the `onWidgetAttach` template method?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`indexOf`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-indexOf) on the `gridview`. You need to pass it the `node` as argument, which is the HTML element representing the row. In Ext JS 6, grid rows are HTML tables, so the button's row element can be found from the button element `b` as `b.el.up('table')`. The `gridview` can also be found as `b.up('gridview')`. So you get:

```
var rowIndex = b.up('gridview').indexOf(b.el.up('table'));
```

See in action: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/snq

Comment: ouch ... there must be something better ... using this feels kind of weak when upgrading the framework version of the application.

Comment: If using widgetcolumn then use can use control.getWidgetRecord() to get the perticular record.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Drake's answer, I'm using the `event.record` property instead.  Unfortunately, it looks like you have to make the click event have a slight buffer, so it gets the proper record added to it.  This works, but I'm not entirely sure if it's a proper way.  [Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14m3):

```
{
  width: 150,
  xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
  widget: {
    text: 'Button',
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Get row index',
    listeners: {
      buffer: 1,
      click: function(button, event, eOpts) {
        var record = event.record;
        alert(store.find('postid', record.get('postid'), 0, false, true, true))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the onWidgetAttach

> A function that will be called when a widget is attached to a record. This may be useful for doing any post-processing.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html#cfg-onWidgetAttach

The function has both widget and record parameter.
You can do widget.record = record, and then the button will have the record member which you can access in the click listener