# Grid Widget column - on widget change, how to update grid store

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a requirement to display combobox and datefield in Grid columns. So used widgetcolumn and created grid with those fields.

But now on changing data in combobox or datefield, new values should be updated in grid store so that after going to next page and coming back, values should persist in previous pages.

Can someone let me know how I can achieve this?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/183r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option1**: Use both widget and cell editor.

Add CellEditing plugin and set editor to same component as widget.

```
{ xtype: 'widgetcolumn', text: 'Gender', dataIndex: 'gender', flex: 1, 
                    widget: { xtype: 'combo', store: genderStore, displayField: 'name', valueField: 'value'},
                    editor: { xtype: 'combo', store: genderStore, displayField: 'name', valueField: 'value'}
},
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1843

**Option2**: Manually update the record.

I feel this solution is better.

```
widget: {xtype: 'datefield',
            listeners:{
                select: function(datefield, value, eOpts){
                    var rowIndex = datefield.up('gridview').indexOf(datefield.el.up('table'));
                    var record = datefield.up('gridview').getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    record.set('dob', value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1842

To get rowIndex in widgetColumn, I referenced ["How to get rowIndex in extjs widget column" DrakeES's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184487/how-to-get-rowindex-in-extjs-widget-column/32185273).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution i could find.
The function "getWidgetRecord" is not findable with the search.
It is discribed within the widget config description.
Have a look at the following Links.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html#cfg-widget
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html#cfg-widget

> A config object containing an xtype.
>
> This is used to create the widgets or components which are rendered into the cells of this column.
>
> This column's dataIndex is used to update the widget/component's defaultBindProperty.
>
> The widget will be decorated with 2 methods: getWidgetRecord - Returns 
>   the Ext.data.Model the widget is associated with. getWidgetColumn - 
>   Returns the Ext.grid.column.Widget the widget was associated with.

```
widget:{
    xtype:'combo',
    editable: false,
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
        fields:['name','text'],
        data:[
            {"name":"integer", "text":"Integer"},
            {"name":"float","text":"Float"}
        ]
    }),
    listeners:{
        select: function(combo, value, eOpts){
            var record = combo.getWidgetRecord();
            record.set('type', value.get('name'));
        }
    },
    valueField:'name',
    displayField:'text',
    allowBlank: false
}
```

or

```
widget: {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    allowBlank: false,
    listeners:{
        change: function(textfield, value, eOpts){
            var record = textfield.getWidgetRecord();
            record.set('field', value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am having a doubt related to this answer.Will 'allowBlank: false'  work for widget column . Am facing an issue where allowBlank is not working on widget

Comment: I did some Tests in Fiddle.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/30b3
Looks like, there is a problem with 6.0.2.
It ignores editable:false
If i switch from 6.0.2 to 6.7.
allowBlank and editable are working just fine

But! 6.7 is not availible as GPL!
The latest version is 6.0.2.
Sencha stopped releasing GPL-Version since the aquisition of Idera.
You are also not allowed to use the paid versions "6.7, 7.x" in a open source "GPL" project.
This is why i dropped extjs as framework.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort :)